# Import PhpBB2 users into django-auth

Tags: django, phpbb, django-authentication

Is there an elegant way to take the phpbb user table from the version 2 series, and import the users into my django auth_users table?

I'm looking to outright dumb the old table completely, but don't want to lose the users.

I'm aware that the password column is just a md5 hash of the user's password, but inserting the user with md5$$userpasswordhashere doesnt seem to work, the user just gets redirected back to the admin interface. no error messages are presented.

I did see this: http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/915/ on django snippets, and the comments say that the default backend should work... but no luck.

Any alternate ideas would be welcome. By alternate, i mean ways of getting users to reset their own passwords. I'd perfer not to write my own authentication backend that this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually does work. Using md5$$hashgoeshere will obtain the intended results.

Django debug toolbar was actually the problem here.